# Power BI and Workfront api connector

Tags: api, powerbi, workfront-api

I want to bring in workfront data into power bi for reporting. Is there any free api to use as a connector between these two?

Answer (score 0):

There are some third party services you can **Buy** for your purpose, like-

[SyncHub](https://www.blackballsoftware.com/integrate-workfront-with-powerbi)

[tray.io](https://tray.io/connectors/microsoftpowerbi-workfront-integrations)

As you need to spent money for third parties, you can think about some process to develop which will connect to WorkFront and fetch data for you daily basis. Then just store them to your own database like - MySql, MSSQL. Then connect to the database from Power BI.

Alternatively you can Export your data to CSV or other format from WorkFront and then connect to the File from Power BI.

Comment: Thanks mk for the response. Are there any free api's available to do the same? Unfortunately i dont have any database to fetch the data into and exporting is also not an option.

Comment: No, as per my knowledge. But you can build your own API or data fetching process.